# Why does left clicking a button run the function for right clicking a button? Python, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, right-click, minesweeper

I'm trying to make a simple version of minesweeper using python. I have two functions, one for left clicking a button, to reveal the amount of bombs touching that button or if its a bomb, and another for right clicking a button to flag it.

```
def count_of_bombs(row, col):
    count = 0
    for y in range(len(board)):
        if y >= row-1 and y <= row+1:
            for x in range (len(board[y])):
                if x >= col-1 and x <= col+1:
                    if board[y][x] == 1:
                        count += 1
    return count

def clicked(row, col):
    if board[row][col] == 1:
        tk.Button(cv2, text='B', width=2, height=2, fg='blue').grid(row=row,column=col)
    elif board[row][col] == 0:
        tk.Button(cv2, text=count_of_bombs(row, col), width=2, height=2, fg='red').grid(row=row, column=col)

def right_button_clicked(chosen_row, chosen_col):
    if board[chosen_row][chosen_col] == 0:
        button = tk.Button(cv2, text="*", fg = "red", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: right_button_clicked(current_i, current_j))
        button.grid(row=chosen_row, column=chosen_col)
        button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, current_row=chosen_row, current_col=chosen_col: right_button_clicked(current_row, current_col))
        board[chosen_row][chosen_col] = 2
    elif board[chosen_row][chosen_col] == 2:
        button = tk.Button(cv2, text="", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: right_button_clicked(current_i, current_j))
        button.grid(row=chosen_row, column=chosen_col)
        button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, current_row=chosen_row, current_col=chosen_col: right_button_clicked(current_row, current_col))
        board[chosen_row][chosen_col] = 0
    elif board[chosen_row][chosen_col] == 1:
        button = tk.Button(cv2, text="*", fg="red", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: right_button_clicked(current_i, current_j))
        button.grid(row=chosen_row, column=chosen_col)
        button.bind("<Button-3>",lambda e, current_row=chosen_row, current_col=chosen_col: right_button_clicked(current_row, current_col))
        board[chosen_row][chosen_col] = 3
    elif board[chosen_row][chosen_col] == 3:
        button = tk.Button(cv2, text="", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: right_button_clicked(current_i, current_j))
        button.grid(row=chosen_row, column=chosen_col)
        button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, current_row=chosen_row, current_col=chosen_col: right_button_clicked(current_row, current_col))
        board[chosen_row][chosen_col] = 1
```

However, when I left click a button, it runs the function for flagging the tile. But if I left click a button that has already been flagged, nothing happens. When right clicking, it works as normal, a blank tile gets flagged and a flagged tile gets unflagged.

Here's the entire code in case I overlooked something outside of the two functions.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

start_time=time.time() #starting the time
windows = tk.Tk()
windows.title('tk')
windows.geometry('450x700')

cv1 = tk.Canvas(windows, bg='white')
cv1.pack(side=TOP)
cv2 = tk.Canvas(windows, bg='white')
cv2.pack(side=BOTTOM)
cv3 = tk.Canvas(windows, bg='white')
cv3.pack(side=RIGHT)

bombs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
np.random.shuffle(bombs)# randomizing the list so bombs are random
n = 16
board = list()
for i in range(0, len(bombs), n): #changing the list into a 16x16 2d list
    board.append(bombs[i:i+n])

c = 0
myText = """Welcome to MineSweeper!"""
def title():
    if c == 9:
        seconds = time.time() - start_time
        myText = "Success!! ElapsedTime:{:.0f} seconds".format(seconds)
        msg = Message(cv1, text=myText, width=190)
        msg.grid(row=0)
    if c != 9:
        myText = "Welcome to MineSweeper!"
        msg = Message(cv1, text=myText, width=180)
        msg.grid(row=0)

title()

def count_of_bombs(row, col):
    count = 0
    for y in range(len(board)):
        if y >= row-1 and y <= row+1:
            for x in range (len(board[y])):
                if x >= col-1 and x <= col+1:
                    if board[y][x] == 1:
                        count += 1
    return count

def clicked(row, col):
    if board[row][col] == 1:
        tk.Button(cv2, text='B', width=2, height=2, fg='blue').grid(row=row,column=col)
    elif board[row][col] == 0:
        tk.Button(cv2, text=count_of_bombs(row, col), width=2, height=2, fg='red').grid(row=row, column=col)

def right_button_clicked(chosen_row, chosen_col):
    if board[chosen_row][chosen_col] == 0:
        button = tk.Button(cv2, text="*", fg = "red", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: right_button_clicked(current_i, current_j))
        button.grid(row=chosen_row, column=chosen_col)
        button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, current_row=chosen_row, current_col=chosen_col: right_button_clicked(current_row, current_col))
        board[chosen_row][chosen_col] = 2
    elif board[chosen_row][chosen_col] == 2:
        button = tk.Button(cv2, text="", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: right_button_clicked(current_i, current_j))
        button.grid(row=chosen_row, column=chosen_col)
        button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, current_row=chosen_row, current_col=chosen_col: right_button_clicked(current_row, current_col))
        board[chosen_row][chosen_col] = 0
    elif board[chosen_row][chosen_col] == 1:
        button = tk.Button(cv2, text="*", fg="red", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: right_button_clicked(current_i, current_j))
        button.grid(row=chosen_row, column=chosen_col)
        button.bind("<Button-3>",lambda e, current_row=chosen_row, current_col=chosen_col: right_button_clicked(current_row, current_col))
        board[chosen_row][chosen_col] = 3
    elif board[chosen_row][chosen_col] == 3:
        button = tk.Button(cv2, text="", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: right_button_clicked(current_i, current_j))
        button.grid(row=chosen_row, column=chosen_col)
        button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, current_row=chosen_row, current_col=chosen_col: right_button_clicked(current_row, current_col))
        board[chosen_row][chosen_col] = 1

def both(row, col):
    clicked(row, col)
    right_button_clicked(row, col)


for i in range(16):
    for j in range(16):
        if board[i][j] == 0:
            button = tk.Button(cv2, text="", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: both(current_i, current_j))
            button.grid(row=i, column=j)
            button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, current_row=i, current_col=j: right_button_clicked(current_row, current_col))
        if board[i][j] == 1:
            tk.Button(cv2, text="", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: both(current_i, current_j)).grid(row=i, column=j)
            button.grid(row=i, column=j)
            button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda e, current_row=i, current_col=j: right_button_clicked(current_row, current_col))

tk.mainloop()
```

I tried removing the button.bind function from the second set of buttons that are mines

```
if board[i][j] == 1:
    tk.Button(cv2, text="", width=2, height=2,command=lambda current_i=i, current_j=j: both(current_i, current_j)).grid(row=i, column=j)
```

but that just made it so when I right clicked a mine, nothing happens.

I tried switching around the order of the functions in the both() function,

```
def both(row, col):
    clicked(row, col)
    right_button_clicked(row, col)
```

but that didn't change anything.

I'm not sure if I made a mistake somewhere, if there's something simple I overlooked, or if I need to completely restart and implement everything in a different way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your complaint.  You have created your buttons so that either a left or a right click calls the `both` function, which calls both the left and right click handlers.  What were you expecting this to do?  Did you mean to have `command` call `clicked`, and bind button 3 to `right_button_clicked`?

Comment: Ah okay thank you. I changed the command in the button to clicked() and got rid of the both() function. However now when I flag a mine(right click), unflag a mine(right click it again) and then left click on it, the button I clicked on does nothing, and the button in the bottom right corner (board[16][16]) is the one that gets changed. After that if I left click it again nothing happens, but I can still flag and unflag it normally.

Comment: You're still using lambdas to do the commands, right?  You need that to capture the right element number (i,j).

Comment: In your creation loop at the bottom, you are not assigning the `tk.Button` to `button` in the `==1` clause.  You don't really need the `if`; your processing is identical for both.  Once I do that, things work pretty well.